# Add country in itinerary after schengen visa approved with Stamp Report Back After Travel

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I applied for a Schengen visa in the Greek embassy. My travel plans presented were My Country-Greece-Italy-Greece-My Country. My visa was granted but with a stamp of Report Back After travel. The embassy told me to report back to them after the travel and returned back to my country..

Can I change my travel plan to visiting one more Country? Greece-Italy-Paris France-Greece?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schengen visa change in itinerary](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104933/schengen-visa-change-in-itinerary)

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate suggestion, as the embassy has apparently requested OP report back to them after the trip. Quite what they expect from that report is unclear, and I don't think any answer which fails to address that (unusual) request could be considered a complete answer to this question.

Comment: It might help to know the OP’s country to establish if a report back instruction is normal practice there or something out of the ordinary specific to the OP

Comment: @Traveller I agree the country makes a diff here, my ex who is chinese for a report back in her passport but it was simply to confirm she actually left they did not care about changes during the trip we were told